# how to apply contions in inner joins in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have there different tables lets say A ,B ,C.

From table A the query I am using is

```
select a.status, a.resolution, a.ID 
from A a ;
```

From table B I have to fetch `B.destID` when `A.ID` matches

For that I am using

```
select b.destID 
from B b 
where b.ID = A.ID  ;

if  b.destID exists then 
    select newstatus  
    from C 
    where C.id = B.destID 
else 
    select newstatus  
    from C 
    where C.id = A.ID
```

Can somebody help me in combining all these three queries into one?

Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
 select a.status,a.resolution, 
    Coalesce(c2.newstatus, c1.newstatus) newStatus 
 from A Left Join B On B.ID = A.ID 
   Left Join C c1 On c1.id = A.Id
   Left Join C c2 On c2.id = B.destID
```

Comment: i also want a.status,a.resolution columns form A but i didn't see these columns in the above query ..can u include these columns plz

Comment: Just add them to the Select clause.

Comment: thanks for ur help @Charles Bretana the actual problem iam facing is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143101/how-to-combine-these-queries-in-sql-server

Comment: instead of suggesting me everybody is down voting this issue...atleast u plz go through this issue and help me